# Saved file not showing up in directory using C++

Tags: c++, file, object, save, fstream

I have a simple I/O program, but when I save a file it is not being created in the project directory or anywhere else on my computer. It all compiles fine, all the functions work, but upon loading I receive a blank file. How can I fix this?

I'm using Xcode also.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    class Person
    {
        public:
            Person(){cout << "\n\tA person has been built. Edit their Info";}
            ~Person();

            void setName(string nameIn){name = nameIn;}
            void setOccupation(string occupationIn){occupation = occupationIn;}
            void setLocation(string locationIn){location = locationIn;}
            void setReferences(string referencesIn){references = referencesIn;}

            string getName(){return name;}
            string getOccupation(){return occupation;}
            string getLocation(){return location;}
            string getReferences(){return references;}

        private:
            string name;
            string occupation;
            string location;
            string references;
    };

    void CreatePerson();
    void EditPerson();
    void DisplayPerson();
    void SavePerson();
    void LoadPerson();

    Person * Pptr;

    int main(void)
    {
        char choice[10];
        Pptr = new Person();

        cout << "\n\tPersonnel Database";

        while (choice[0] != 'q')
        {
            cout << "\n\t--------------MAIN MENU---------";
            cout << "\n\t (C)reate a Person";
            cout << "\n\t (E)dit a Person";
            cout << "\n\t (D)isplay a Perosn";
            cout << "\n\t (S)ave a Perosn";
            cout << "\n\t (L)oad a Person";
            cout << "\n\t (Q)uit";
            cout << "\n\t";

            cin >> choice;

            switch(choice[0])
            {
                case 'c': CreatePerson();break;
                case 'e': EditPerson();break;
                case 'd': DisplayPerson(); break;
                case 's': SavePerson();break;
                case 'l': LoadPerson();break;
                case 'q': cout << "Exiting...";break;
                default: cout <<"\n\tInvalid Entry";
            }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    void CreatePerson()
    {
        Pptr = new Person();

    }

    void EditPerson()
    {
        string tempInfo;

        cout << "\n\tEdit Personnel record";

        cout << "\n\tName: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,tempInfo);
        Pptr->setName(tempInfo);

        cout << "\n\tOccupation: ";
        getline(cin,tempInfo);
        Pptr-> setOccupation(tempInfo);

        cout << "\n\tLocation: ";
        getline(cin,tempInfo);
        Pptr->setLocation(tempInfo);

        cout << "\n\tReferences: ";
        getline(cin,tempInfo);
        Pptr->setReferences(tempInfo);
    }

    void DisplayPerson()
    {
        cout << "\n\tPersonnel  Record";
        cout << "\n\tName: " << Pptr->getName();
        cout << "\n\tOccupation: "<< Pptr->getOccupation();
        cout << "\n\tLocation: " << Pptr->getLocation();
        cout << "\n\tReferences: " << Pptr->getReferences();
    }

    void SavePerson()
    {
        try
        {
            ofstream data;
            data.open("personnelData.file",ios::out);

            data << Pptr->getName() << "\n"; // \n is the delimiter
            data << Pptr->getOccupation() << "\n";
            data << Pptr->getLocation()<< "\n";
            data << Pptr->getReferences() << "\n";

            data.close();
            cout << "\n\tSuccessfully Saved";
        }
        catch (exception e) {
            cout << "\n\tcould not save Person.";
        }
    }

    void LoadPerson()
    {
        try
        {
            string tempInfo;
            Pptr = new Person();

            ifstream in;
            in.open("data.txt", ios::in);

            getline(in, tempInfo);
            Pptr->setName(tempInfo);

            getline(in, tempInfo);
            Pptr->setOccupation(tempInfo);

            getline(in, tempInfo);
            Pptr->setLocation(tempInfo);

            getline(in, tempInfo);
            Pptr->setReferences(tempInfo);
        }
        catch (exception e) {
            cout <<"\n\tUnable to load file";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Q: Have you tried looking at it under the debugger?  Q: Are you sure you get into "SavePerson", and do you actually see the line "Successfully Saved" being printed out?  Are you *sure* you don't have "personnelData.file" *anywhere* on your disk?

Comment: success is being printed 
@RavindraBagale why does it go to the bin? How can I set it to the project dir or one of my choosing?

Comment: just checked bin not there as well

Answer (score 1):

Your file is in the `bin` directory; check there.

Because you are not given the file path that means it is created by default in the `bin` directory.

To save it in your required directory, you need to give your required directory path.

Comment: i tried a path. Would not save there as well. also ran it in release mode. Nothing

Comment: i just set a path to the desktop. Don't get a file on the desktop but when I load the info comes up. ??

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions: Do all the following, then omit stages:

1) Call `SavePerson` directly from main, to make sure it's get called.

2) Give the file name a full path, like `c:\\file.txt`.

3) Try a different extension than `.file`, like, for example, `.txt`.

Comment: 2 and 3 I've done and SavePerson is being called because Display is displaying info I inputted but I have no clue where the file goes. I checked the bin, the path I set and can't find anything. I'm on a mac by the way